# GET to POST not working

Tags: javascript, http, post, get

I want to make get request to post request of the below code -

```
       <html>
       <head>
         <script language="JavaScript">
          function redirect()   {
             if (window.focus)
           self.focus();
                this.location = '/test/GetReports?id=       
           <%=System.currentTimeMillis()+session.getId()%>';
         }
      </script>
    <title>Downloading Document</title>
         </head>
   <body marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' onload='javascript:redirect()'>
   </body>
 </html>
```

To achieve this I've done below  -

```
   <html>
   <head>
     <script language="JavaScript">
     function redirect()    {
     if (window.focus)
        self.focus();
      location =  '/test/GetReports?id=<%=System.currentTimeMillis()+session.getId()%>';
      var form = document.createElement("form");
      form.setAttribute("method", "post");
      form.setAttribute("action", location);
       form.submit();
      }
   </script>
   <title>Downloading Document</title>
   </head>
    <body marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' onload='javascript:redirect()'>
  </body>
 </html>
```

But it does not make any difference. Still this request is Get. Please let me know what else needs to be done.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: test this `form.setAttribute("method", "post");` on Chrome Console and see if it works

Comment: Just to point out, the `language` attribute on the script element is obsolete. You should use `type="text/javascript"` instead.

Comment: Is you second attempt even working? I don't see how it sends the GET request

Comment: I have tested using your code and it works fine :) The only difference is that my location was pointing to another location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually sending GET data with the POST form. Parameters specified in the URL are always considered GET data.

To illustrate what that means, if you have a form that looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="test.html?gid=1">
    <input name="pid" value="2">
</form>
```

...the server will receive the value `gid` as GET and `pid` as POST. Whatever is in the URL is sent as GET, regardless of what method the form uses.

So to make your code work you need to create a field inside the form to have it send the data as POST.

```
function redirect() {
    if (window.focus) self.focus();
    loc = '/test/GetReports';   // note: no parameters here
    var form = document.createElement("form");

    // create the input element
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("name", "id");
    input.setAttribute("value", <%=System.currentTimeMillis()+session.getId()%>);
    form.appendChild(input);

    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", loc);
    form.submit();
}
```

Also note that I renamed `location` to `loc` --- you might have problems otherwise since `location` would point to `window.location`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I tried the above code but redirect() function itself is not getting executed. This above jsp is called from  one servlet and this servlet is opening a new pop up window from JS. This below code snippet is opening new window and then above jsp is called. var f = document.getElementById('Form1');
loc = '/ocs/Displayservlet?AcctNum='+acctNum+'; f.setAttribute("method", "post"); f.action = loc; parent.window.open('','TheNewWindow','width=640,height=480,toolbar=no);f.submit();So this servlet call is post but when I try the above code then redirect()dn't work.Any clue?

Comment: Can anyone please put light on it?

Comment: That is completely unrelated to the original question. Please post it as a new question instead.

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem. I had to add document.body.appendChild(form); and double quote was missing input.setAttribute("value", "<%=System.currentTimeMillis()+session.getId()%>"); Thank you for your help!